# recursively database filling with multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, json, recursion, multidimensional-array

I would like to recursively access the id field and libelle field to fill my database. I tried the following script I fill only the first level of id and libelle.(where idTypeCaategorie = 0). It's just a part of my array.

I want fill just two field in my data table 'menu1'='libelle' and 'id'=id, and for each sub-level of libelle it would be great to concatenate the parent libelle with the child libelle. –

my datatable stucure :

structure columns >>>>> id(int(10) | newspaper_index(=8) |menu_level(int) | menu1 (*)|menu2(*) |menu3(*) | menu4 (*)| menu5(*) | menu6(*) | menu7(*)| ; its the strucure menu1 is libelle of the first level and menu2 to menu7 are libelle children

exemple 1: Univers Bebe(menu1) (id : .....) menu_level=1

exemple 2: Univers Bebe(menu1) > Lait et cereale(menu2) (id :....) menu_level=2

exemple 3: Univers Bebe(menu1) > Lait et cereale(menu2) > lait 1er age (menu3)(id:.....) menu_level=3

*=varchar
 I want  put information from array in my database with this above structure 
Example Array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 288
            [libelle] => Univers BÃ©bÃ©
            [idTypeCategorie] => 0
            [nomImage] => 1905.jpg
            [ponderation] => 1
            [fils] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2228
                            [libelle] => Laits & cÃ©rÃ©ales
                            [idTypeCategorie] => 1
                            [nomImage] => 2002.png
                            [ponderation] => 1
                            [mea] => 2067
                            [fils] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1024
                                            [libelle] => Lait 1er Ã¢ge
                                            [idTypeCategorie] => 2
                                            [nomImage] => 
                                            [ponderation] => 1
                                            [nbProduits] => 9
                                            [fils] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1025
                                            [libelle] => Lait 2Ãšme Ã¢ge
                                            [idTypeCategorie] => 2
                                            [nomImage] => 
                                            [ponderation] => 2
                                            [nbProduits] => 10
                                            [fils] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1026
                                            [libelle] => Croissance
                                            [idTypeCategorie] => 2
                                            [nomImage] => 
                                            [ponderation] => 3
                                            [nbProduits] => 19
                                            [fils] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 290
                                            [libelle] => Petit dÃ©jeuner
                                            [idTypeCategorie] => 2
                                            [nomImage] => 
                                            [ponderation] => 4
                                            [nbProduits] => 9
                                            [fils] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [4] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 2595
                                            [libelle] => CÃ©rÃ©ale
                                            [idTypeCategorie] => 2
                                            [nomImage] => 
                                            [ponderation] => 5
                                            [nbProduits] => 10
                                            [fils] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2230
                            [libelle] => Repas de BÃ©bÃ©
                            [idTypeCategorie] => 1
                            [nomImage] => 1974.png
                            [ponderation] => 2
                            [mea] => 2482
                            [fils] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 3651
                                            [libelle] => Repas Ã  base de lÃ©gumes
                                            [idTypeCategorie] => 2
                                            [nomImage] => 
                                            [ponderation] => 3
                                            [nbProduits] => 28
                                            [fils] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 3656
                                            [libelle] => PurÃ©e pour bÃ©bÃ©
                                            [idTypeCategorie] => 2
                                            [nomImage] => 
                                            [ponderation] => 4
                                            [nbProduits] => 8
                                            [fils] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 3652
                                            [libelle] => Repas Ã  base de viande
                                            [idTypeCategorie] => 2
                                            [nomImage] => 
                                            [ponderation] => 5
                                            [nbProduits] => 29
                                            [fils] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 3653
                                            [libelle] => Repas Ã  base de poisson
                                            [idTypeCategorie] => 2
                                            [nomImage] => 
                                            [ponderation] => 6
                                            [nbProduits] => 16
                                            [fils] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [4] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 3654
                                            [libelle] => Repas Ã  base de volaille
                                            [idTypeCategorie] => 2
                                            [nomImage] => 
                                            [ponderation] => 7
                                            [nbProduits] => 18
                                            [fils] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [5] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 3657
                                            [libelle] => Repas BIO
                                            [idTypeCategorie] => 2
                                            [nomImage] => 
                                            [ponderation] => 8
                                            [nbProduits] => 4
                                            [fils] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3660
                            [libelle] => Diner & Soupe
                            [idTypeCategorie] => 1
                            [nomImage] => 1989.png
                            [ponderation] => 3
                            [mea] => 3764
                            [fils] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 3661
                                            [libelle] => Pour le diner
                                            [idTypeCategorie] => 2
                                            [nomImage] => 
                                            [ponderation] => 1
                                            [nbProduits] => 16
                                            [fils] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 3662
                                            [libelle] => Soupe pour bÃ©bÃ©
                                            [idTypeCategorie] => 2
                                            [nomImage] => 
                                            [ponderation] => 2
                                            [nbProduits] => 9
                                            [fils] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2227
                            [libelle] => GoÃ»ter et desserts
                            [idTypeCategorie] => 1
                            [nomImage] => 2003.png
                            [ponderation] => 4
                            [mea] => 309
                            [fils] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 294
                                            [libelle] => Jus de fruits
                                            [idTypeCategorie] => 2
                                            [nomImage] => 
                                            [ponderation] => 1
                                            [nbProduits] => 1
                                            [fils] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1021
                                            [libelle] => PurÃ©e de fruits
                                            [idTypeCategorie] => 2
                                            [nomImage] => 
                                            [ponderation] => 2
                                            [nbProduits] => 26
                                            [fils] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 3663
                                            [libelle] => Compote
                                            [idTypeCategorie] => 2
                                            [nomImage] => 
                                            [ponderation] => 3
                                            [nbProduits] => 18
                                            [fils] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1023
                                            [libelle] => Biscuit
                                            [idTypeCategorie] => 2
                                            [nomImage] => 
                                            [ponderation] => 4
                                            [nbProduits] => 3
                                            [fils] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [4] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1022
                                            [libelle] => Yaourt pour bÃ©bÃ©
                                            [idTypeCategorie] => 2
                                            [nomImage] => 
                                            [ponderation] => 5
                                            [nbProduits] => 8
                                            [fils] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [5] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 3664
                                            [libelle] => CrÃšme dessert
                                            [idTypeCategorie] => 2
                                            [nomImage] => 
                                            [ponderation] => 6
                                            [nbProduits] => 11
                                            [fils] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 295
                            [libelle] => Couche-culottes
                            [idTypeCategorie] => 1
                            [nomImage] => 2029.png
                            [ponderation] => 5
                            [mea] => 1713
                            [fils] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 2576
                                            [libelle] => 3 - 6 Kg
                                            [idTypeCategorie] => 2
                                            [nomImage] => 
                                            [ponderation] => 1
                                            [nbProduits] => 7
                                            [fils] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 308
                                            [libelle] => 2 - 9 Kg
                                            [idTypeCategorie] => 2
                                            [nomImage] => 
                                            [ponderation] => 2
                                            [nbProduits] => 6
                                            [fils] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 309
                                            [libelle] => 7 - 18 Kg
                                            [idTypeCategorie] => 2
                                            [nomImage] => 
                                            [ponderation] => 3
                                            [nbProduits] => 10
                                            [fils] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 310
                                            [libelle] => 9 - 25 Kg
                                            [idTypeCategorie] => 2
                                            [nomImage] => 
                                            [ponderation] => 4
                                            [nbProduits] => 13
                                            [fils] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [4] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 311
                                            [libelle] => Culottes
                                            [idTypeCategorie] => 2
                                            [nomImage] => 
                                            [ponderation] => 6
                                            [nbProduits] => 10
                                            [fils] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [5] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 3829
                                            [libelle] => Lingettes
                                            [idTypeCategorie] => 2
                                            [nomImage] => 
                                            [ponderation] => 7
                                            [nbProduits] => 18
                                            [fils] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 296
                            [libelle] => Toilette & soins
                            [idTypeCategorie] => 1
                            [nomImage] => 2031.png
                            [ponderation] => 6
                            [mea] => 968
                            [fils] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 312
                                            [libelle] => Lingettes
                                            [idTypeCategorie] => 2
                                            [nomImage] => 
                                            [ponderation] => 1
                                            [nbProduits] => 18
                                            [fils] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 313
                                            [libelle] => Savons & gels lavants
                                            [idTypeCategorie] => 2
                                            [nomImage] => 
                                            [ponderation] => 3
                                            [nbProduits] => 7
                                            [fils] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 314
                                            [libelle] => Autres soins
                                            [idTypeCategorie] => 2
                                            [nomImage] => 
                                            [ponderation] => 5
                                            [nbProduits] => 6
                                            [fils] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 4183
                                            [libelle] => Coton pour bÃ©bÃ©
                                            [idTypeCategorie] => 2
                                            [nomImage] => 
                                            [ponderation] => 6
                                            [nbProduits] => 4
                                            [fils] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2229
                            [libelle] => PuÃ©riculture
                            [idTypeCategorie] => 1
                            [nomImage] => 2030.png
                            [ponderation] => 7
                            [mea] => 36176
                            [fils] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 2732
                                            [libelle] => HygiÃšne et bain pour bÃ©bÃ©
                                            [idTypeCategorie] => 2
                                            [nomImage] => 
                                            [ponderation] => 7
                                            [nbProduits] => 2
                                            [fils] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2214
            [libelle] => Fruits & lÃ©gumes
            [idTypeCategorie] => 0
            [nomImage] => 1916.png
            [ponderation] => 2
            [fils] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1136
                            [libelle] => Fruits
                            [idTypeCategorie] => 1
                            [nomImage] => 1928.png
                            [ponderation] => 1
                            [mea] => 202
                            [fils] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1139
                                            [libelle] => Pommes & Poires
                                            [idTypeCategorie] => 2
                                            [nomImage] => 
                                            [ponderation] => 1
                                            [nbProduits] => 5
                                            [fils] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1137
                                            [libelle] => Agrumes
                                            [idTypeCategorie] => 2
                                            [nomImage] => 
                                            [ponderation] => 2
                                            [nbProduits] => 3
                                            [fils] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )
```

```
    for($i=0; $i< $nb_elem ; $i++){ // while we're not at the end of big array 

    foreach($tab_categories as $key => $objet){//for each element(objet) which has menu and foreach menu we fill database with id and libelle
        $id = $tab_categories[$i] -> id;
        $menu1 = utf8_decode($tab_categories[$i] -> libelle);
        //echo $id."|".$menu1."\n";
        $req="INSERT IGNORE INTO menu_itm (id, menu1)
        VALUES('".$id."','".addslashes($menu1)."');"; //addslashes permet de gérer les caractère spéciaux
                    $req=$bd->prepare($req);
                    $req->execute();

    }
}
```

I tried this :

function pour_un_objet($obj) {
        foreach($obj ->Object  as $cle => $array){//...
            if(is_array($array) && count($array)>0 ){//si le champ de l'objet courant est un tableau et si ce dernier n'est pas vide 
                pour_un_fils($array);
                return true; //fils exploitable
        }
            else
                return false; // fils non exploitable,

}

function pour_un_fils($input){
    array_walk_recursive($input, function ($input) {//for each term is a table while we're not at the end of the table as soon as we find a label and an id

for($cf=0;$cf

```
    foreach($input as $subkey ){// input is an array son subkey is his field (id, libelle ... )
        if($subkey=="libelle" || $subkey=="id") 
            get_menu($id,$term);// only if you arrive on a field or libelle id
            return true;
        }   
        else
            return false;           
  }
 }
```

}
Any help great appreciation.

Comment: think about using recursive function instead of for loop!!!

Comment: like array_walk_recursive() ?

Comment: it may be a good candidate!!!

Comment: I doubt it : (from the manual page) "Any key that holds an array will not be passed to the function."  - It's only usable on one dimensional arrays

Comment: What does the database table look like? i.e. Edit your question to show what you want the output database table to look like from your example data.

Comment: you can write your own recursive function. please provide more details about what you want to do.

Comment: I want fill just two field in my data table 'menu1'='libelle' and 'id'=id, and for each sub-level of libelle it would be great to concatenate the parent libelle with the child libelle.

Comment: please look at my answer and try to fill that schematic with your statements

Comment: I tried a similar idea,

Comment: You understood my problem :).

Comment: but for the case where fils is null what do we?

Comment: Converted the code to use the mysql database with all prepared queries. I will must likely add the 'tree build' from the database routine later today. This will then provide all the 'usefull' routines.

Comment: ok thanks Ryan, did you want the json file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's done,I found another way to retrieve the data that  I wanted.

```
function RecursiveAddOfProducts($listeSon,$listParents_libelle) {
    $result = array();$Product=array();

    if($listeSon) {

       foreach($listSon as $key => $currentNode {
        if(!empty($currentNode)) { // If the product has a son
          $newParent_libelle = $listParents_libelle; 
           $newParent_libelle[] = utf8_decode($currentNode['libelle']); 
           $newParent_id=$listParents_id;
           $newParent_id[] = $currentNode['id']; 
           $produit=array_merge($newParent_id,$newParent_libelle);
           $menu_niveau=count($Product)-1;
          ProductInsert($Product,$menu_niveau);
          RecursiveAddOfProducts($currentNode['fils'], $newParent_libelle); 
         }
       }
    }
```

}
    $listeParents=array();

```
RecursiveAddOfProducts($tab_categories,$listParents);
```

My insert function works like it :

```
function ProductInsert($tab,$menu_niveau){
$menu_list = "";
$column_value = "";
for($i=1;$i<= $menu_level ;$i++){
    if($menu_list != '')
        $menu_list .= ', ';
    $menu_list .= "menu".$i;
    if($column_value != '')
        $column_value .= ', ';
    $column_value.= "'".addslashes($tab[$i])."'";
        //var_dump($column_value);
    }
    $req="INSERT IGNORE INTO menu_itm (id, ".$menu_list.",menu_niveau)
    VALUES(".$tab[0].",".$column_value.",'".$menu_level."')";
    echo $req."</br>";
    sql($req);
```

}

I would like all to thank you for your help, all the persons which contributed was of a big help. I learnt a lot. Thanks to Ryan vincent also for your help, you gave many of your time, I am grateful to you for it.;)

Answer (score 0):

OK, just wrote this class, seems to work with the test data included.

```
    <?php
class recursiveGrab{
    public $output;
    public $target;
    public $input;
    private $tempSub = array();

    public function __construct ($subject, $target){
        $this->input = $subject;
        $this->masterData = $subject;
        $this->target = $target;
        $this->getTopLevel();
    }

    private function getTopLevel($level = null){
        ($level == null) ? $dataset =$this->input : $dataset = $level;
        $target = $this->target;
        $i = 0;
        foreach($dataset as $key=>$value){
            foreach($target as $k=>$needle){
                if($key == $needle && !is_array($value)){$this->tempSub[$needle]= $value;};
            }


            }
            if(count($this->tempSub) >= 1 ){
                $this->output[] = $this->tempSub;
            }
                if(is_array($value) && count($value) >= 1){
                    $this->downLevel($value);
        }
    }

    private function downLevel($value){
        $this->getTopLevel($value);
    }
}

//testData

$tst = array('staff' => array(
    'id'=>'1',
    'name'=>'Director',
    'subordinates'=>array(
        'id'=>'2',
        'name'=>'upperManagement',
        'subordinates'=>array(
            'id'=>'3',
            'name'=>'Office Manager',
            'subordinates'=>array(
              'id'=>'4',
              'name'=>'office staff',
              'subordinates'=>array(

              ),
              array(
                'id'=>'5',
                'name'=>'it manager',
                'subordinates'=>array()
              )
            )
        )
    )
)
);

$mapped = new recursiveGrab($tst, array('id', 'name'));
$twoD = $mapped->output;
$values = "";
$rec = count($twoD);
for($i=0;$i<$rec;$i++){
$values .=" (?,?)";
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO myDB (id, name) VALUES".$values;
echo $sql."<br>";
$counter = 1;
foreach ($twoD as $row){
    echo "\$stmt->bindParam({$counter}, {$row['id']}, PDO::PARAM_INT)<br>";
    $counter++;
    echo "\$stmt->bindParam({$counter}, {$row['name']}, PDO::PARAM_STR)<br>";
    $counter++;
}
?>
```

Output's the following:

```
INSERT INTO myDB (id, name) VALUES (?,?) (?,?) (?,?) (?,?) (?,?)
$stmt->bindParam(1, 1, PDO::PARAM_INT)
$stmt->bindParam(2, Director, PDO::PARAM_STR)
$stmt->bindParam(3, 2, PDO::PARAM_INT)
$stmt->bindParam(4, upperManagement, PDO::PARAM_STR)
$stmt->bindParam(5, 3, PDO::PARAM_INT)
$stmt->bindParam(6, Office Manager, PDO::PARAM_STR)
$stmt->bindParam(7, 4, PDO::PARAM_INT)
$stmt->bindParam(8, office staff, PDO::PARAM_STR)
$stmt->bindParam(9, 5, PDO::PARAM_INT)
$stmt->bindParam(10, it manager, PDO::PARAM_STR)
```

Comment: this is recursive script ?? Why ?

Comment: It works, it's part of my problem thanks. I see more easily  'id' and 'libelle'. But I wont change structure parent->child-<sub-child ect

Comment: pre-process your data array with that, and then you can use simple foreach() on the 2D result to build the query for your INSERT.  Just let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ... Why :(

Comment: @kakame94 what did you try? link to a phpfiddle.org if you need to update code

Answer (score 0):

This is a schematic of what you should do:

```
function ParseArray(array){
      foreach (array as $item)
      {
            sql statement
            if($item->fils != null)
                 ParseArray($item->fils)
      }

}
```

Comment: but for the case where fils is null what  do  we?

Comment: as you can see first you do what you want by a node and then you go inner level if there is any(fils!=null)!!! so in this manner you will parse all of the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive walk of an existing multi-way Tree.

Tested on version PHP 5.3.29 and later.

The code:

- Outputs to a database,
- Works with the 'tree' as an array rather than `stdClass` objects.
- The 'build menu from database' script added.

It uses functions rather than *classes* but has been organized into separate files.

Source:

- [Process the JSON data: Q29792309-index-recursively-database-filling.php](http://pastebin.com/amWZJGZJ)
- [Tree Walk: Q29792309-tree-walk.php](http://pastebin.com/5vh5wz6K)
- [Select Menu Items: Q29792309-select-query.php](http://pastebin.com/aABS68SA)
- [Insert Menu Item:  Q29792309-insert-query.php](http://pastebin.com/2AUHrPMC)
- [Update Menu Item:  Q29792309-update-query.php](http://pastebin.com/qHqznHW1)
- [Truncate Menu Table: Q29792309-truncate-table.php](http://pastebin.com/qnVjLGVb)
- [Test Data: Q29792309_json.txt](http://pastebin.com/EVu5PjTz)
- [Database Table q29792309 DDL](http://pastebin.com/4w2S7D7w)
- [Build the menu from the database: Q29792309-index-build-tree-from-database.php](http://pastebin.com/zLWLyhXx)

To make the 'tree walk' useful we shall have it call a 'closure' function
that has the following signature:

```
function ($childNode, $parentNode);
```

**The code:**

The function that does the work of 'walking' the tree:

```
/**
 * Apply processing to the current node and it's parent node.
 *
 * @param node $currentNode
 * @param node $parentNode
 * @param closure $processNode
 * @return void This is all 'side effects'
 */
function walkTree($currentNode, $parentNode, /* closure */ $processNode)
{
// call the closure - but only if the parent is set...
if (!empty($parentNode)) {
    $processNode($currentNode, $parentNode);
}

// process the children of this node
foreach ($currentNode['fils'] as $childNode) {

walkTree($childNode, $currentNode, $processNode); // recurse for every node
}
return;
}
```

**An example 'closure' to insert the menu node into the database:**

```
/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Closure to be called for every node with a parent in the tree
 *
 *  It will insert the data into the database using a prepared query
 */
$processNode  = function ($childNode, $parentNode)  {

insertMenuItem($parentNode['id'], $childNode['id'], $childNode['libelle']);
};
```

**How to use the routines**

1) Create a global database `mysqli` connection

```
$DB_HOST = "localhost";
$DB_USER = "test";
$DB_PASSWORD = "test";
$DB_TO_USE   = "testmysql";

$db = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD, $DB_TO_USE);
```

2) Include / Define the Tree Processing routines

```
/** -----------------------------------------------------------------
 * Tree Process Functions...
 *
 * function walkTree($currentNode, $parentNode,  $processNode);
 */
include __DIR__ .'/Q29792309-tree-walk.php';

/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Closure to be called for every node with a parent in the tree
 *
 *  It will insert the data into the database using a prepared query
 */
$processNode  = function ($childNode, $parentNode)  {

insertMenuItem($parentNode['id'], $childNode['id'], $childNode['libelle']);
};
```

3) Include the Database Processing Routines

```
/** -----------------------------------------------------------------
 * Query functions...
 */
/**
 * function selectMenuList($whereClause = '',  $valueList = array(), $orderBy = '')
 */
// example: $rows = selectMenuList('menu_id = ? OR parent_menu_id = ?', array(1024, 2229));

/**
 *  displayMenuList($rows);
 */
include __DIR__ .'/Q29792309-select-query.php';

/**
 * function insertMenuItem($parentMenuId, $menuId, $title)
 */
include __DIR__ .'/Q29792309-insert-query.php';

/**
 * function updateMenuItem($parentMenuId, $menuId, $title)
 */
include __DIR__ .'/Q29792309-update-query.php';

/**
* function truncateTable($tableName = 'q29792309')
*/
include __DIR__ .'/Q29792309-truncate-table.php';
```

4) Process the tree

```
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Process all the data
 */

// ------ Load the JSON data
$json = file_get_contents('Q29792309_json.txt');

$sourceTree = json_decode($json, true);
// show test data...
echo $EOL, '  -------- Source Tree Start ---------';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($sourceTree);
echo '</pre>';
echo $EOL, '  -------- Source Tree End ---------';

// Empty the table...
truncateTable('q29792309');

echo $EOL, '  -------- Tree walk Start ---------';
walkTree($sourceTree, null, $processNode);
echo $EOL, '  -------- Tree walk  End ---------';

// display the inserted rows
$rows = selectMenuList();
displayMenuList($rows);

exit(); // redundant but a clue when reading where the main processing ends
```

Sample Test Data:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 0
    [libelle] => Root
    [idTypeCategorie] => 
    [nomImage] => 
    [ponderation] => 
    [fils] => Array
       (
           [0] => Array
               (
                    [id] => 288
                    [libelle] => Parent: 0 to here: 288
                    [idTypeCategorie] => 0
                    [nomImage] => 1905.jpg
                    [ponderation] => 1
                    [fils] => Array
                       ( ...
```

Output: Inserted Data

```
-------- select rows Start ---------
Parent Menu Id: 0 Menu Id: 288 Title: Parent: 0 to here: 288 isDeleted: 0
Parent Menu Id: 0 Menu Id: 289 Title: Parent: 0 to here: 289 isDeleted: 0
Parent Menu Id: 288 Menu Id: 2228 Title: Parent 288 to here: 2228 isDeleted: 0
Parent Menu Id: 288 Menu Id: 2229 Title: Parent 288 to here: 2229 isDeleted: 0
Parent Menu Id: 2228 Menu Id: 1024 Title: Parent 2228 to here: 1024 isDeleted: 0
Parent Menu Id: 2228 Menu Id: 1025 Title: Parent 2228 to here: 1025 isDeleted: 0
Parent Menu Id: 2229 Menu Id: 1036 Title: Parent 2229 to here: 1036 isDeleted: 0
-------- select rows End ---------    -------- select rows End ---------
```

Comment: thanks for your help I'm actually trying your answer :)

Comment: I completely understand your code but I'm working with big json that I decode with json_decode. How can I add to [libelle] => "Parent". It was just a part of the big array

Comment: I have an error :'</pre><br />  -------- Source Tree End ---------<br />  -------- Tree walk Start ---------<br />walkTree($sourceTree, null, $processNode);PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/ealanmanou/24042015_script_test2_remplir_menu_itm.php on line 194

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/ealanmanou/24042015_script_test2_remplir_menu_itm.php on line 194
<br />  -------- Tree walk  End ---------<br />  -------- outWalkedTree Start ---------<pre>Array'

Comment: just , little precision ,datatable structure > id | newpapers_index | menu_level |menu1| menu2 |menu3.....menu7  , libelle insert into menuX example : row 1  288 |univers bebe | ' ' | ' ' | ...|' '|       rowX  id | univers bebe | new 'libelle' | ' ' |    ect....

Comment: I already have this datatable I want fill collumns with id and libelle , menu1, menu2 ..ect are children . example product  "lait premier âge" give the row> 1024 |newspapers(its for me dont panic) | Univers bebe | lait et cereale | lait premier age

Comment: @kakame94, sorry it wasn't as useful as we wished. I enjoyed writing it though. It is an interesting problem :)