# How do I implement categories in php

Tags: php, mysql

As the title suggests, I want to create category and sub category listing of products for the web store I am working on. Say there is a category named Apparel{parent category} => Shoes, footwear.. etc {child category} and shoes will have all the shoe products.
How do I implement this? ie Should I put all the main categories under one table. Each row would then reference another table?

Comment: Using an existing commerce library of writing your own? You are aware that 'category' -> subCategory' is a `recursive` relationship and not a 'linear' one? imo, Your data structure should reflect this. i.e. do not limit yourself to two levels deep. Someone will want three or more levels. ;-/ imo, Build it into the data structures at the start. You don't have to use it but it can be expanded later without throwing away your data structures and starting again. imo, it is worth looking at some of the open-source libraries that do this already.

Comment: @RyanVincent I am writing code from scratch. Its that recursive relationship that I am concerned about btw.

Comment: If you decide to have a category table with separate sub-categories that is up to you. Swings and roundabout about that. whatever - the sub-categories table must have a column that holds the id of its sub-categories. You can use this to indicate it has further subcatagies. Coding it: In the first instance while you work it out - keep it really simple. So, you may end up doing rather more queries than you like. Whatever. imo, Always start with something simple that works. ;-/ You can refactor it later. imo, For large trees then look at 'nested sets' but later - not now.

Comment: if you want some 'php / mysqli' code that walks trees then this may be worth a look? http://stackoverflow.com/a/29838522/3184785. I will repost the code it required.

Comment: The tree structure and its traversal looks interesting. But that would be a bit too complex as far as this project is concerned, I think I like the way of using columns to identify the subcategories. Simple to implement and maintain.

Comment: I agree - it is worthwhile writing the queries yourself - it it the best way to understand what is happening. I was really just pointing out that there are people to assist if it gets 'awkward' :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how your table look like

```
id | item_name  | parent_id | 
1  | Shoes      | 0         | 
2  | Jackets    | 0         | 
3  | Formal     | 1         | 
4  | Casuals    | 1         | 
5  | Party Wear | 2         |
```

here you can see that your parent category has `parent_id` 0 and all the other sub categories are having id of their parent in `parent_id` column. In this way you can store your products in same table, differentiating them with parent_id

For example : Record 1 i.e Shoes is a parent and having parent_id 0, and record 3,4 are the sub categories of record 1, because they have parent id 1.